# marking same across rows if one of rows satisfy condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I mark as 'abuser' across rows of same ID if one of rows of that ID satisfy a condition?

For example, if I have the following table,

| ID | social score |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

Can I mark rows of ID 1 as all abnormal (because social score of one of rows is 0 ) and mark rows of ID 2 as all normal (because social score of none of rows of ID 2 is 0 )?

| ID | social score | class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 'abnormal' |
| 1 | 2 | 'abnormal' |
| 1 | 3 | 'abnormal' |
| 2 | 3 | 'normal' |
| 2 | 1 | 'normal' |
| 2 | 2 | 'normal' |

If I can, with what python phrase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First find the `ID's` having social score `0`, then use `np.where` to assign `class` values:

```
i = df.loc[df['social score'].eq(0), 'ID']
df['class'] = np.where(df['ID'].isin(i), 'abnormal', 'normal')
```

---

```
   ID  social score     class
0   1             0  abnormal
1   1             2  abnormal
2   1             3  abnormal
3   2             3    normal
4   2             1    normal
5   2             2    normal
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df['class'] = df.ID.apply(lambda x: 'abnormal' if x==1 else 'normal')
```